# Getting current date and time in specific format x++ 2012

Tags: datetime, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, date-formatting

I need to get the date/time in this format. 
2016/05/25 17:08:22

X++ 2012, . i attempted to use DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime()) but not sure the correct parameters

Comment: are you having trouble formatting a date time field? Or do you have problems retreiving the date and time? It's probably easier to format the date and time seperatly

Comment: i'm having trouble getting the time and formatting the date properly. just wondering how i can accomplish both date and the time in that format.

Comment: Hey go through this blog https://stoneridgesoftware.com/working-with-utcdatetime-functionality-in-dynamics-ax-2012/

Comment: Also please refer this https://msdaxerp.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/dates-and-time-functions/ and http://kashperuk.blogspot.co.nz/2014/05/q-session-working-with-utcdatetime-from.html

Answer (score 5):

The following job should give you the idea how to do the formatting.

```
static void FormatDateTimeJob(Args _args)
{
    utcDateTime now = DateTimeUtil::utcNow();
    str formattedOutput;

    formattedOutput = DateTimeUtil::toFormattedStr(
        now, 
        321, 
        DateDay::Digits2, 
        DateSeparator::Slash, 
        DateMonth::Digits2, 
        DateSeparator::Slash, 
        DateYear::Digits4, 
        TimeSeparator::Colon, 
        TimeSeparator::Colon);
    info(formattedOutput);
}
```

Of course you may want to apply a timezone prior to formatting the value like so

```
now = DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(
    now,
    DateTimeUtil::getClientMachineTimeZone());
```

Comment: Also, if you want to change *all* dates in the system, consider setting your regional settings for your target location. As a European I really hate the default (US) setting on many AOS servers.